# Google Chrome Developer Tools - unable to edit CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm using Google Chrome developer tools to try different CSS values on a localhost site e.g. changing "border-width: 1px" to "border-width: 2px".

For some reason I am unable to edit. If I click on "1px", I can type in a new value e.g. "2px" but as soon as I hit return, the value returns back to "1px".

For some reason, it is only affecting one site - all other sites I can edit fine.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Earlier on, I saw a "paused in debugger" notification at the top and the page greyed. Might this have something to do with the problem?

Comment: Could you post the hole CSS class you are trying to modify, maybe there is some error on it and that's the reason Chrome is not reflecting the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the problem was the use @import in the site's style sheet, specifically:

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
```

Once this was commented out, I was able to edit the CSS again.